# Boundaries of rectangles / plots in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am attempting to create a set of graphs using patches.rectangle in matplotlib, but it seems that the blur in the boundaries of the rectangle cause some overlap. For example, if I use these two green rectangles:

http://puu.sh/cpzFw/fe6ed8834d.png

(I didn't have the rep to directly insert the image)

I am not sure how to remove the boundaries. In addition, how would I adapt this to the subplot coordinates as well, as the plot does this too.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Sorry, here is some example code:

```
  for i in range(nrows):
    for (count, num) in enumerate(listx[2 * i + 1]):
      if count == 0:
          rect_start = count
      elif num == listx[2 * i + 1][count-1]:
          length += 1
      elif listx[2 * i + 1][count] != listx[2 * i + 1][count-1]:
          if listx[2 * i + 1][count-1] == '0':
              r1 = ptch.Rectangle((rect_start,i), length, 1, color="blue", fill=True)
              rect.add_patch(r1)
              length = 1
              rect_start = count    
          if listx[2 * i + 1][count-1] == '1':
              r1 = ptch.Rectangle((rect_start,i), length, 1, color="black", fill=True)
              rect.add_patch(r1)
              length = 1
              rect_start = count
          if listx[2 * i + 1][count-1] == '2':
              r1 = ptch.Rectangle((rect_start,i), length, 1, color="red", fill=True)
              rect.add_patch(r1)
              length = 1
              rect_start = count
          if listx[2 * i + 1][count-1] == '3':
              r1 = ptch.Rectangle((rect_start,i), length, 1, color="green", fill=True)
              rect.add_patch(r1)
              length = 1
              rect_start = count
          if not listx[2 * i + 1][count-1].isdigit():
              r1 = ptch.Rectangle((rect_start,i), length, 1, color="yellow", fill=True)
              rect.add_patch(r1)
              length = 1
              rect_start = count
```

Comment: Please provide the minimal example code to reproduce your image.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck setting `ec='none'`.  The edge is drawn with a line (which has a thickness in points), so that will cause some imprecise overlap.
BTW: If you want precise size and an edge-like effect, you can always put a slightly smaller colored rectangle on top of a rectangle of a different color (both with `ec='none'`).